# How to configure cells **not** to evaluate via "Evaluate Notebook"

Tags: cells, evaluation

Is there a way to configure certain cells/sections not to evaluate under "Evaluate Notebook," while still being able to "manually" evaluate them with Shift+Enter?

I have a large notebook with certain sections containing "crucial" code that I want to easily evaluate each time I open the notebook, but also certain sections containing testing, debugging, and other non-essential code that I don't want to evaluate except for when I choose to, ad hoc.

Comment: It would be easy to make your crucial-code cells into [Initialization Cells](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpAnInitializationCell.html).

Comment: That works. Still curious if there's a way to do what exactly I described, so that I could add messy testing code and be sure it would only ever be evaluated manually.